# Session not ending on click of "OnLoggingOut" action

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to log out of a session on a website with the following code. However, seemingly nothing happens when I click on the logout button.

here is my code:

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" OnLoggingOut="Logout_Click"  runat="server" />
```

and c#:

```
public void Logout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Session.Abandon();
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage();


    }
```

This code is not ending the session, and it isn't even redirecting to the login page.

Web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="url"   timeout="20" domain="domain">
      </forms>
    </authentication>
```

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.loginstatus.onloggingout.aspx), your `OnLoggingOut` method should have 1 parameter of type `LoginCancelEventArgs`.

The code you have in the Logout_Click method should be fine, but it's not getting called because your method signature is incorrect.

Comment: What method signature should I be using then?

Comment: Take a look at the MSDN page I linked to. Your `OnLoggingOut` event should be like `void LoginStatus1_LoggingOut(Object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.LoginCancelEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

```
(object sender, LoginCancelEventArgs e)
```

is the actual signature for the OnLoggingOut method. and you do not need the call to session.abandon.

Answer (score 0):

Write a below code on your button click event

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session.Abandon();
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Clear();
    FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

    Response.Redirect("~/LoginPage.aspx");

}
```